# Is this graph concave up on this interval?

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

The graph above is concave up on the intervals: $[-5,0]$ and $[0,5]$.
My question is: Is the graph concave up on this interval $[-5,5]$ ? In other words: Since $x=0$ is a corner, does that effect the concavity of the interval $[-5,5]$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function is concave up (also called [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)) on an interval $I\subset\mathbb R$ if 
$$f(ta+(1-t)b)\leq tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$$ for all $a,b\in I$ and for all $t\in [0,1]$.  Geometrically, this simply means that the line connecting two points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ does not dip below the graph of the function over the interval with endpoints $a$ and $b$.

[image]

Your function does not satisfy this condition for $a=-1$, $b=1$, and any $t\in(0,1)$.  Therefore, it is not concave up on $[-1,1]$ (or any interval whose endpoints lie on opposite sides of the origin).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order for an attribute like this to be true over an interval, the thing it's measuring must also exist over that interval.  Since at $x=0$, this function doesn't have a second derivative, it can't be considered to be concave up (or down) on any interval that includes $0$ in its interior.

Even worse, if we were to construct a series of 2-smooth functions that increasingly approximate the function around 0, the resulting derivative at 0 would be increasingly negative, and thus definitely not concave up.

Comment: This is incorrect.  A function need not be differentiable to be convex.  The absolute value function is convex but not differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Some calculus texts require the derivative to exist in the definition of concavity, so it would depend on the student's textbook.

Comment: @Ekie Perhaps - but this is an everywhere defined continuous function. We should apply a definition that is, well, *applicable*. :)

Comment: the absolute value function is most certainly not concave up.

Comment: @DanUznanski The absolute value function most certainly satisfies the definition of convex or "concave up" that is in my answer.

Comment: I'd at least use < instead of ≤.  Aside from that, well, okay.